# Variable type is null in remote class

Tags: php

Here is my main class

```
class pMr {
    const VERSION = '0.0.3';
    public $_connection;
    private $_sessionName = 'LoginSession';

    public function __construct($function = null) {
        ...
            $this->buildConnection('Predis');
        ...
    }

    private function buildConnection($type = 'Predis') {
        ...
            if($type == 'Redis') {
                ...
            } else if($type == 'Predis') {
                try {
                    $this->_connection = new Predis\Client(array(
                        'host'     => $_SESSION[$this->_sessionName]['hostname'],
                        'password' => $_SESSION[$this->_sessionName]['password'], 
                        'database' => $_SESSION[$this->_sessionName]['database'], 
                    ));
                } catch (ClientException $e) {
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }
                var_dump(gettype($this->_connection));  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when that code runs, I get `string(6) "object"`, which is expected. Now, here is another class, which is loaded inside the main class and then executed (a function is called).

```
class Interface {
    static $_execOnLoad = true;
    public static function getRedisVersion() {
        global $pMr;
        var_dump(gettype($pMr->_connection));
    }
}
```

Now, in that function (when its called), returns NULL. This is the same variable that returns as an object in the above code. Why is this, and what is the work around?

Answer (score 0):

Perform `var_dump($pMr);` for both objects and see its object#. I bet you just have different objects.

Comment: Inside the class, the var_dump returns null, while after the classes is defined ($pMr = new pMr()) it returns all the class info

Comment: @Colum: Doesn't matter what returns var_dump inside, what about object id? Is it the same for both objects?

Comment: Inside the class, the vardump returns NULL. Outside the class, it returns: object(pMr)#1 (2) {
  ["_connection"]=>
  object(Predis\Client)#2 (4) {
    ...

Comment: @Colum: again: **doesn't matter what returns var_dump(gettype($pMr->_connection));**. But does matter if you have the same object you're working with. Do you have **the same object** in both cases?